# OSX - Using different DNS for different network interface

Tags: macos, networking, dns, nslookup

I've an OSX Mountain Lion system and, if it's possible, I need to use different DNS servers for different networks.
I'm going to explain my situation:

I'm at work.
I'm connected to work network (by ethernet) and to personal network (by wifi) with this order in system preferences:

```
1.WIFI (en0)
2.ETHERNET (en2)
```

...because I want to use WIFI by default.

This works fine at IP level. I'm able to surf on internet and i reach work IPs.
But it doesn't work at DNS level.
If I try nskookup, DNS is always the DNS assigned by WIFI network and If I try to reach a work address (resolved by work DNS) it always use WIFI DNS.

Is there a way to force a new DNS for en2 interface ?

I tried to add a resolver configuration.
Assuming that work ip addresses are 10.x.x.x and search domain is "ginger"
This is my file "/etc/resolver/ginger":

```
domain ginger
nameserver 10.0.0.70
nameserver 10.0.0.71
nameserver 156.1.1.1
nameserver 156.1.1.2
```

I don't know if it is correct and if it's possible to do what I want using resolver config.

Thanks.

Comment: Think about this: how is it supposed to know BEFORE making a DNS query which interface is going to be ultimately used to forward packets that go to the address that is going to result from the DNS query. Hint: this is easy to solve if you have a time machine for predicting the future.

Answer (score 1):

If the domains in your work network is different from those on the Internet, you should be able to configure a DNS server to do so.

However, it may need some time to learn how DNS works before you really understand how to configure it.

Try to read a bind documentation.

Basic configuration is as below:
1. install a DNS server (say bind) on your PC. 
2. configure it as a recursive server, resolve domain1.com, domain2.com recursively from the DNS in your work network (assumes domain1.com and domain2.com are domains in your work network), and resolve others recursively from the Internet DNS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/277160/110637) solved it.

In short: you may create a list of Locations (in Network Preferences) and each location keep its own network settings (including DNS servers).